# How to declare a "Record" type with partial of specific keys in typescript?

Tags: typescript

Now, I got this:

```
type T_PlatformKey= 'pf1' | 'pf2' | 'pf3'
type T_PlatformInfo = {
    key: T_PlatformKey
    name: string
    [k: string]: any
}
```

I'd like to declare a "Record" type like this:

```
type T_platforms = Record<T_PlatformKey, T_PlatformInfo>

const platforms: T_Platforms = {} // here is the problem
```

If i don't declare all properties:

```
Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Record<T_PlatformKey, T_PlatformInfo>': pf1, pf2, pf3 ts(2739)
```

I've tried other way like this:

```
interface I_Platforms {
    pf1: T_PlatformInfo
    pf2: T_PlatformInfo
    pf3: T_PlatformInfo
}
const platforms: Partial<I_Platforms> = {} // it works
```

uh, it works, but...? not very smart.

(btw, forgive my terrible english, thx)

Comment: How do you plan to use `T_platforms`? I suspect `Record` isn't what you're looking for. Perhaps `Map`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use mapped type (similar to `Record` implementation) and specify that each key is optional:

```
type T_Platforms = { [Key in T_PlatformKey]?: T_PlatformInfo }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAKg+gBQDYENgDMD2AnAtgaQhCgF4oByMdARnKgB8KqAmOxy9AZnIFgAoUJFiJUGHLgCSAOyykoAb35RlUANZEAXMORoseQiCUqpKXBC0BnYNgCWUgOZHlAbVWXrd+wF0tKKYb4AX35+QWh4HTE8Czl5KGcDKDttUT0CIi8Afi0I1PFpWWC+fgBjTCkrKDA86JyRXXEYsnlAoA)

Answer (score 19):

This now also works, and much nicer and readable:

```js
type T_Platforms = Partial<Record<T_PlatformKey, T_PlatformInfo>>;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKg+gBQDYENgDMD2AnAtgaQhCgF4oByMdARnKgB8KqAmOxy9AZnIFgAoUJFiJUGHLgCSAOyykoAb35RlUANZEAXMORoseQiCUqpKXBC0BnYNgCWUgOZHlAbVWXrd+wF0tKKYb4AX35+QWh4HTE8CzkEFGxgGxQkAB4AJQgAYxwAExSI0T0CIgAabULxaSwAPmqAbhC+bKkrKDAK6K0C3XEYsnlAoA)